# Select JSON sub-node

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I am querying the Wikipedia API and am getting JSON back that looks like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=cessna%20172&pithumbsize=500&format=json

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"normalized":[{"from":"cessna 172","to":"Cessna 172"}],"pages":{"173462":{"pageid":173462,"ns":0,"title":"Cessna 172","thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/Cessna_172S_Skyhawk_SP%2C_Private_JP6817606.jpg/500px-Cessna_172S_Skyhawk_SP%2C_Private_JP6817606.jpg","width":500,"height":333},"pageimage":"Cessna_172S_Skyhawk_SP,_Private_JP6817606.jpg"}}}}
```

Using .Net Core 2.2, what is the proper way to get the image thumbnail out of this (the `source` property in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing JSON is not a built in feature in *.Net core 2.2* so you will want to add the [Newtonsoft.Json package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to the project with `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json --version 12.0.3`.

From there include `Newtonsoft.Json` by adding `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` to the top of the file. and `using System.Net;` to use `WebClient`.

From there the code retrieves the string from the url. `JObject.Parse` parses the string as a `JObject`. We can get the property you want by chaining indexers: `["query"]["pages"]["173462"]["thumbnail"]["source"]`.

#### Full source:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=cessna%20172&pithumbsize=500&format=json";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string rawString = client.DownloadString(url);
            var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(rawString);
            string thumbnail = jsonResult["query"]["pages"]["173462"]["thumbnail"]["source"];
            Console.WriteLine(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good and was the approach I was taking, you need a `ToString` on the jsonResult as `JObject` can not be assigned to a `string`.   However, I get "sequence contains no elements"

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will have to define a class and de-serialised the json. Example :

```
Batch batch  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
```

More details [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).

However, at times, just to get one/two values, it might be overhead to use an entire class structure. In this case, a quick way might be to parse the json dynamically. Example which is taken from [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing):

```
public void JValueParsingTest()
{
    var jsonString = @"{""Name"":""Rick"",""Company"":""West Wind"",
                        ""Entered"":""2012-03-16T00:03:33.245-10:00""}";

    dynamic json = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

    // values require casting
    string name = json.Name;
    string company = json.Company;
    DateTime entered = json.Entered;

    Assert.AreEqual(name, "Rick");
    Assert.AreEqual(company, "West Wind");            
}
```

Comment: Does this only handle top-level JSON?  I need something 3 levels deep as per the link

Comment: I didn't test the above code but in my opinion, it can handle all the child nodes as well.